# Regression analysis and overruling pseudoreplication

Tags: regression

I am not a statistician and is new to this field. I have four populations from four different sites and multiple observations from each site. What I am trying to do to check whether a significant relation occurs between the location of site and the population trait by using linear regression. Should I use the mean of each population for analysis. But when I do this I am just considering the mean, the variability of the data is overlooked and if I use it as independent observation I may be pseudo replicating the data. And when I use only the mean the results are non significant which becomes significant when individual observations considered. What should I do? What will be the right approach to do it? 
I apologise if the question appears vague. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by applying mixed model regression. In mixed model two effects are considered- fixed and random. When applying mixed model the overall variability of the data is considered. The replicates are treated as random effects and their variability is also considered while estimation of relationship. This solves the problem of pseudorepliaction and includes the variability of each sample. Here is the reference in detail of how to do it- http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~cschwarz/Stat-650/Notes/PDFbigbook-JMP/JMP-part017.pdf